# Automate ssh connection with expect in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, expect

Im trying to do a shell script using expect to automate connection because it's not allow to use ssh keys. Its my first script with expect and I find a little bit confuse for me. In this case I can connect by ssh but I can't close the connection, I don't know how to do, any idea ??

```
#!/bin/bash

user=pepe

host=server

pass=`cat /tmp/password.txt`

COMMAND=df

PASSWORD=$pass expect -c "

    spawn ssh $user@$host

    expect "*assword*"

    send \$env(PASSWORD)\r

    expect {

     "*be*" {send $COMMAND\r;interact}}

"
```

Comment: Take a look at my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write Expect scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate fix is to specify the command as an argument to `ssh` -- then the connection will be made and the command will run and the connection will close

```sh
#!/bin/bash

user=pepe
host=server
pass=`cat /tmp/password.txt`

COMMAND=df

PASSWORD=$pass expect -c "
    spawn ssh $user@$host $COMMAND
    expect \"*assword*\"
    send \$env(PASSWORD)\r
    expect eof
"
```

A couple of things to note:

- `expect eof` will gracefully wait for the spawned command to exit
- I've escaped the internal double quotes.

---

Next step is to tidy up the quoting/escaping. When embedding code for another language in a shell script, using a quoted heredoc is the best way to avoid quoting hell. This means that all the shell variables need to passed to expect via the environment

```sh
#!/bin/bash

export user=pepe
export host=server
export pass=`cat /tmp/password.txt`

export cmd=df

expect << 'END_EXPECT'
    spawn ssh $env(user)@$env(host) $env(cmd)
    expect "*assword*"
    send $env(pass)\r
    expect eof
END_EXPECT
```

---

Last thing I'd do is to reduce the exposure of the password. Expect is built on the [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) language, which is fully capable of reading files:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

export user=pepe
export host=server
export pass=`cat /tmp/password.txt`

export cmd=df

expect << 'END_EXPECT'
    set fh [open /tmp/password.txt]
    gets $fh pass
    close $fh

    spawn ssh $env(user)@$env(host) $env(cmd)
    expect "*assword*"
    send $pass\r
    expect eof
END_EXPECT
```

And make sure the permissions on that password file are as restrictive as possible:

```sh
mv /tmp/password.txt ~/.local/share/pass.txt
chmod 0400 ~/.local/share/pass.txt
```